# multi level embedded documents in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to edit some fields in a document

```
{
"_id": 5,
"Applicates": [

        {
            "School": "UCONN",
            "Name": "Mike",
            "Research": "cloud computing",
            "Budge": 5000,
            "appId": 100,
            "Time": "5/5/5-6/6/6",
            "citizenship": "us",
            "Evaluators": [
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 1
                },
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 2
                },
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 3
                }
            ],
            "Major": "csc",
            "preAwards": "none",
            "Advisor": "Dr. pie"
        },
        {
            "School": "psu",
            "Name": "Tom",
            "Research": "topology",
            "Budge": 7500,
            "appId": 101,
            "Time": "1/1/1-2/2/2",
            "citizenship": "us",
            "Evaluators": [
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 1
                },
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 2
                },
                {
                    "abstractScore": null,
                    "goalsObjectivesScore": null,
                    "evalNum": 3
                }
            ],
            "Major": "MAT",
            "preAwards": "none",
            "Advisor": "Dr. cool"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to update all the null values. I have been trying to do it in python with $set but had no luck. Here is what I was trying

```
posts.update({"_id" : 5,"Applicates.Name":"Mike","Application.Evaluators.evalNum":"1"},{"$set":{"Applicates.Evaluators.abstractScore" :10}})
```

So I'm asking how do I update each null field separately? What I wanted my code above to do is update the first `abstractScore` in Evaluators which is in `{"Applicates.Name" : 'Mike"}`. I also want to update the other 2 `abstractScore` for `{"Applicates.Name" : 'Mike"}` and the 3 for `{"Applicates.Name" : "Tom"}` all separately. Of course I want `goalsObjectivesScore` updated too but I'm trying to do 1 step at a time.

I have looked around quit a lot and cant seem to find a solid answers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you want to update all null values by 10 or other values ?

Comment: Update them all how? What the context around updating all the null values? How do you want to pick which array element to update?

Answer (score 0):

I got close enough with this line of code. It's not exactly what I wanted, but I made it work for what I needed.

```
posts.update({"_id":5,"Applicates.appId":100},{"$set":{"Applicates.$.Evaluators.0.abstractScore": 10}})
```